# Why schedule threads between cpu cores expensive?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture

There are some articles which refers to so called core affinity and this technique will bind a thread to a core which would decrease the cost of the scheduling threads between cores. In contrast there is my question.
Why operating system doing this job take more time when scheduling threads between cores.

Comment: Because some levels of cache are private per-core, so they'll be cold on a different core.  (And worse than that, dirty on the old core requiring write-back before they can be read.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Is his/her question referring to caches or do you think it's referring to the higher computational cost of scheduling without affinity since there are more cores to schedule threads on?

Comment: @JackHumphries: in most OSes, it's not so much that a task is "scheduled to a core", as that the kernel running on *each* core grabs the highest-priority task that's currently runnable, subject to restrictions from the affinity mask.  (The scheduler function on this core will only consider tasks whose affinity mask matches this core.)  I think the OP is just distorting what the article said about the costs of having a thread bounce around between cores.  It's mostly not the actual cost of CPU time in the kernel's scheduler function, it's that the task runs slower on a new core.

Comment: @PeterCordes Got it. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably misinterpreting something you read.  It's not the actual *scheduling* that's slow, it's that a task will run slower when it moves to a new core because private per-core caches will be cold on that new core.

(And worse than that, dirty on the old core requiring write-back before they can be read.)

**In most OSes, it's not so much that a task is "scheduled to a core", as that the kernel running on each core grabs the highest-priority task that's currently runnable, subject to restrictions from the affinity mask**. (The scheduler function on this core will only consider tasks whose affinity mask matches this core.)

There is no single-threaded master-control program that decides what each core should be doing; the scheduler in normal kernels is a cooperative multi-threaded algorithm.

It's mostly not the actual cost of CPU time in the kernel's scheduler function, it's that the task runs slower on a new core.